# jewelry on 3d models

Tags: mesh

been struggling for a long time how to create 3d pave on 3d models( not flat models) i tried geomtray nodes and particle propetries but no luck with that, heres an exmaple picture of what im talking about: https://ibb.co/j8cxW9d
https://ibb.co/tCwpt2v how every gem and prong position so right facing the right way ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that it was made manually by hand. Here is the trick that you can use:

1. Install Jewel Craft add-on: https://github.com/mrachinskiy/jewelcraft

   This is optional, but it is very useful to get the right sized gems and prongs.
2. Set up right snap settings:

[image]

With face snapping and align rotation to surface, it is easy to place gems on surface with correct rotation:

[image]

3. Then it is done, you can quickly add prongs by special command in Jewel Craft. They will be aligned to gems and properly scaled. You can use 60 deg, but I prefer 0 deg position:

[image]

4. Set up local transform and individual origins:

[image][image]

That is useful to fix rotations of prongs quickly:

[image]

5. Adding cutters is also possible using this add-in:

[image]

so that you can use them in boolean operator like this:

[image]

I send cutters and prongs in separate collections and set boolean difference and union using that collections.

Answer (score 2):

You may use this simple method,
its auto duplicate instance per-face and aligned
[image]